# Cannot build gtk-sharp 3 on Mac OS X via Mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk3, automake, gtk#

I've been at this for hours and it's really driving me crazy. Cannot find a solution anywhere on the internet.

I got the latest gtk-sharp code from their Github repository, but am unable to get past the autoconf stage. At first, it was failing because it could not find the Mono C# compiler, but I was able to fix that by adjusting the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable. Now, it is giving me the same issue about GTK, which I definitely have installed (via brew) - both 2.0 and 3.0, and adjusted the variable.

Does anyone have any pointers whatsoever?

`automake.sh` output:

```
$ ./autogen.sh  --prefix=`pkg-config --variable=prefix mono`
Running /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize...
Running aclocal  ...
Running autoheader...
Running automake --foreign  ...
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.10.0/lib/pkgconfig/../.. ...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '505' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '20' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether we're on Windows... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.0.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking size of void *... 8
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking size of off_t... 8
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for MONO_DEPENDENCY... yes
checking for gacutil... /usr/bin/gacutil
checking for al... /usr/bin/al
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for PROFILER... yes
checking for gmcs... /usr/bin/gmcs
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for GIO... yes
checking for PANGO... yes
checking for ATK... yes
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.0.0) were not met:

Package 'x11', required by 'gdk-3.0', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH` value: `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.10.0/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/lib/pkgconfig:`

I even tried setting `GTK_LIBS`, to no luck: `/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/`

If there is any info at all I can provide, please let me know and I will be happy to!

Comment: Check the error message again. It's erroring on the X11 package, not GTK. You'll want to disable the X11 backend for GDK, and enable the Quartz one. (This is accomplished with a `./configure` switch, but I can't remember which one.)

Comment: I have successfully installed gtk#3 on osx using the gtk packages from macports using the quartz variant. You probably need a 64 bit mono as well because macports will install 64 bit binaries by default

Comment: I am not using brew, but it seems that the gtk formula has a switch to enable the quartz backend using the parameter --without-x11 when installing

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a homebrew Formulae to build this.

```
class GtkSharp3 < Formula
  homepage "http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp"
  url "https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/archive/2.99.3.tar.gz"
  version "2.99.3"
  sha256 "6212a59809951e032f6d2712d5a6680203d0d6869f1c09127c4b9fb3c35ad384"

  depends_on "autoconf" => :build
  depends_on "automake" => :build
  depends_on "libtool" => :build
  depends_on "pkg-config"
  depends_on "gtk+3"
  depends_on "pango"
  depends_on "harfbuzz"
  depends_on "glib"
  depends_on :x11

  def install
    ENV.append_path "PKG_CONFIG_PATH", "#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig"
    ENV.append_path "PKG_CONFIG_PATH", "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig"

    inreplace "autogen.sh", "libtoolize", "glibtoolize"
    system "./autogen.sh", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make", "install"
  end

  test do
    # `test do` will create, run in and delete a temporary directory.
    #
    # This test will fail and we won't accept that! It's enough to just replace
    # "false" with the main program this formula installs, but it'd be nice if you
    # were more thorough. Run the test with `brew test gtk-sharp`. Options passed
    # to `brew install` such as `--HEAD` also need to be provided to `brew test`.
    #
    # The installed folder is not in the path, so use the entire path to any
    # executables being tested: `system "#{bin}/program", "do", "something"`.
    system "false"
  end
end
```

Just save this as `/usr/local/Library/Formula/gtk-sharp3.rb`, then run `brew install gtk-sharp3`. You will also need to add `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` when you run mono so that it can find the additional packages.

Since Gtk#3 is not stable yet, it cannot be included in the official homebrew repository.

Comment: Hello David
I did not found /usr/local/Library/Formula/ folder, but I created a folder which you mentioned in the answer. copy your text gtk-sharp3.rb
Tried to execute brew install gtk-sharp3
Throws error: No available formula the name gtk-sharp3.
MAC OS version 10.12.6